# Ubuntu 16.04 network not available

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo T440p, but I cannot get wireless or wired connections to work. Here is what I've found so far:

```
**lshw -C network:**
```

gave no result

```
**iwconfig:**
```

lo no wireless extensions,
wlan0 no such device,
eth0  no such device

```
**/etc/network:**
```

interfaces (5)
 file used by ifup(8) ifdown(8)
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-essid myssid
wpa-psk mypasscode

The command

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

failed and instructed to look at `journalctl -xe` for details:
(partial details)

```
wpa_supplicant: successfully initialized
wpa_supplicant: Could not interface with wlan0 flags
wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Driver does not support authenication/association or connect commands
```

Any help and or suggestions are greatly appreciated.